# Why i Can't see the gui editor on android 2.2?

Tags: android

I new in the android developing.
 I define new project ( using eclipse ) that will work on android 2.2 - but i dont see any gui  editor on the Res->layout->main.xml
( when i define new project on android 1.6 i see this gui editor )

What i need to do to see this gui editor ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

right click on your file : open with "layout editor" ?

Then you should have a tab at the bottom to see it in layout mode ou source mode.

Comment: I see the tab - but there is no controls that i can drag in

Comment: if waiting does not solved the problem, maybe there is an issue with you ADT plugin, try updating it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it will take some time to load the GUI editor. Wait for some time.